# how to change instance type in runtime

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

how to change instance type in run time

I have running  t2.small instance, I stooped the instance and run it with t2.medium instance but the instance running t2.small

```
ec2:
 key_name: "{{key_name}}"
 region: "{{aws_region}}"
 state: running
 instance_type: t2.medium
 instance_ids: "{{ item.id }}"
 aws_access_key: "{{aws_access_key_id}}"
 aws_secret_key: "{{aws_secret_access_key}}"
```

it seems that ansible ignore from the instance_type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just run your instance using a new size, you should modify your instance size first, after stopping it, then run it afterwards.

**Modify your instance size**> [[ reference ]](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-ModifyInstanceAttribute.html)

```
ec2-modify-instance-attribute <instance id> --instance-type <new type>
```

You should also take note of [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-resize.html), specifically>

> You can resize an instance only if its current instance type and the
>   new instance type that you want are compatible in the following ways:
>
> - Virtualization type. Linux AMIs use one of two types of
>     virtualization: paravirtual (PV) or hardware virtual machine (HVM).
>     You can't resize an instance that was launched from a PV AMI to an
>     instance type that is HVM only. For more information, see Linux AMI
>     Virtualization Types.
> - Network. Some instance types are not supported
>     in EC2-Classic and must be launched in a VPC. Therefore, you can't
>     resize an instance in EC2-Classic to a instance type that is available
>     only in a VPC unless you have a nondefault VPC. For more information,
>     see Instance Types Available Only in a VPC.
> - Platform. All Amazon EC2
>     instance types support 64-bit AMIs, but only the following instance
>     types support 32-bit AMIs: t2.nano, t2.micro, t2.small, t2.medium,
>     c3.large, t1.micro, m1.small, m1.medium, and c1.medium. If you are
>     resizing a 32-bit instance, you are limited to these instance types.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I got this error ""[Errno 2] No such file or directory"

Comment: command aws ec2-modify-instance-attribute --region "{{aws_region}}" --instance-id "{{ item.id }}" --instance-type t2.medium

Comment: I needed to install aws cli

Answer (score 0):

Command is

> aws ec2 modify-instance-attribute --instance-id i-0a83c51db11ca537f
>   --instance-type t2.micro

More info can be found at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-resize.html